# How to prevent "submit" event from a form in Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, leaflet

I'm combining Leaflet 1.0 with the Leaflet.draw plug-in.  The idea is that a user can draw a rectangle on the map (called `tempLayer`), and then fill out a form in a popup to enter some data. Following [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144695/submit-a-form-from-within-a-leaflet-popup), I was able to create a form within a Leaflet popup.  I used `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the page from refreshing when the user presses the `Submit` button.

```
// create user-editable form in popup
function createUserEditablePopup(tempLayer) {
  var popupContent = '<form role="form" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label class="control-label col-sm-5">Enter data:</label>' +
    '<input type="string" placeholder="type here" id="input1"/>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<div style="text-align:center;" class="col-xs-4">' +
    '<button type="submit">Submit</button></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</form>';
  tempLayer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();

  // prevent the form from submitting and refreshing page
  $(".form").submit(function(e) {
    // do some logic

    // prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

This works well, unless the user happens to click in either a different spot on the drawn item, or on the map before submitting the form.  The popup is still bound to the layer created from the drawing (and the popup will open if the user clicks on the rectangle again), but now clicking `Submit` causes the entire page to refresh.  Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a42b4e9c/1/).

**So, how can I prevent the page refresh event from firing, even if the user causes the popup to move?**

Comment: Move the `e.preventDefault()` to be the first line in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the popup is dynamically created, the jquery selector `.form` should not get applied to it. In order for dynamically created controls/elements to be caught you need to use the `.on` method attached to the body of the document.  All of this code should appear outside of your `createUserEditablePopup` method.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.form', mySubmitFunction);

function mySubmitFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // This should really be the first line

    // Other logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!  Question: why should `e.preventDefault()` be the first line?

Comment: @user2441511: I have 2 personal reasons really. The first is that it's a common standard and let's the next developer know immediately that the function should prevent the submission. The second is that if the method exits out for any reason (an exception, a logical return or something of the like), this will not be called and the browser will perform the submission anyway.